# how to exclude a state from US shipping in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have enabled free shipping for all the states under US and configured table rates for all the states under Canada.

As shipping fare is costly to Hawaii, i would like to remove it from free shipping.
is this possible with default "Free shipping" module in Magento?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the Table Based Shipping module for this. Go into the configuration and change to your website (the dropdown in the upper left corner). Then in the Shipping Methods screen, export the file. Then you edit that with all the states (minus Hawaii) with a minimum amount and then reupload the file and you are good to go.

I cannot seem to attach an example file of how I have done this. If necessary I can email this file to you if you find a way to get it to me.

EDIT:

I will just post the contents of the file here. Copy this into a csv file and upload.
Hopefully its length won't annoy anybody:

```
"Country","Region/State","Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
USA,AL,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,AR,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,AZ,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,CA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,CO,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,CT,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,DE,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,FL,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,GA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,IA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,ID,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,IL,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,IN,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,KS,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,KY,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,LA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MD,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,ME,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MI,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MN,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MO,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MS,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,MT,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NC,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,ND,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NE,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NH,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NJ,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NM,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NV,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,NY,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,OH,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,OK,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,OR,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,PA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,RI,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,SC,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,SD,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,TN,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,TX,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,UT,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,VA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,VT,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,WA,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,WI,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,WV,*,49.0000,0.0000
USA,WY,*,49.0000,0.0000
```

Comment: It should be noted that this excludes both Hawaii and Alaska.